# Enfity Framework Query data starting from an element without load all children

Tags: entity-framework

I do have a subscription based app. Each subscription has many Customers, Employees etc..

I Would like to query the data like this:

```
var subscription = context.Subscriptions.Include(s => s.Customers).Find(id); 
var myQueryCustomers = subscription.Customers.where(...);
```

However I know that, at line 1, the `Include(s => s.Customers)` will retrieve **ALL** Customers from this subscription.

I would like to query Customers data only at line 2

How can I start from a `Subscription` object to make queries to another sub properties without flood the server with all Customers unnecessary data?

Comment: `var myQueryCustomers = context.Customers.Where(x => x.SubscriptionId == id && ...);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compose your query expression and feed it to Entity Framework then use .Select() to retrieve the Entity or data from the entity model you want. For example:

```
var subscriptionAndFilteredCustomers = context.Susbscriptions.Where(s => s.SubscriptionId == id)
  .Select(s => new {Subscription = s, Customers = s.Customers.Where(...).ToList()})
  .SingleOrDefault();
```

This will return an object containing the Subscription as well as a collection of matching customers from that subscription without eager-loading all customers on the subscription.

Note that Accessing the .Customers collection on the returned Subscription will trigger a lazy-load of the customers, so use the returned customers collection for the filtered data. It's for this reason that I generally recommend that code doing these types of queries are at a level where they do not return Entities for consumption, but rather compose View Models or DTOs (for API) to be returned instead to avoid lazy load triggers outside of a context scope.